# Route to backbone same route

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have the route 'availability/exceptions' which routes to the function `availabilityExceptions` and which works fine:

```
    return Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            'availability/exceptions(/:key1)(/:value1)': 'availabilityExceptions',
        }
        ...
```

I want to be able to route to that function no matter what follows 'availability/exceptions'. E.g. 'availability/exceptions/some_key/some_val', 
'availability/exceptions/some_key/some_val/some_key2/some_val2', 'availability/exceptions/some_key/some_val/some_key2/some_val2/some_key3/some_val3' etc 
should all go to availabilityExceptions and passing through whatever comes after 'availability/exceptions'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ***splat** to accomplish what you're asking. It consists of a asterisk followed by a string. So you would set up your route as follows:

```
appRoutes: {
  'availability/exceptions(/*string)': 'availabilityExceptions',
}
```

and this would match any number of URL components that follow 'exceptions'. 'string' can be replaced with any other text of your choice. The part of the URL after `exceptions` gets passed as a parameter to your function.

So if you navigated to `availability/exceptions/some_key/some_val/some_key2/some_val2`, your function can handle it as follows:

```
availabilityExceptions: function(enteredURL) {
//enteredURL equals "some_key/some_val/some_key2/some_val2"
}
```